# Jersey JAX-RS: Specifying /* as base URL pattern

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a Dynamic Web application, and because of the requirements, I am specifying two types of servlet mappings in the web.xml file; Faces Servlet & Jersey(JAX-RS implementation).

My problem is, that if I try to use '/*' as the base url-pattern in the Jersey configuration, then the resources of Faces Servlets stop working, i.e., nothing happens if I make REST call to those resources, otherwise everything works fine if I place something like'/rest/*' in the Jersey Configuration. My web.xml file looks like this:

```
<!-- Jersey -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.saf.web.v2.beans</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Faces Servlet -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is there a way to specify the Jersey mapping so there is nothing in the url-pattern but '/*' and Faces Servlet resources also work fine at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you define that Jersey should serve all requests (this is what `/*` means) the Faces Servlet doesn't have a chance any more. So in general: There is no such way.

Maybe you could work around this be mapping Jersey to `/rest` and writing an own Servlet mapped to `/*` which [dispatches](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) to one of the other servlets. I would not recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I fixed it by using 
     /rest/* 
       for jersey's servlet
 and other part of application can have any other url-pattern, as in your case it is  *.xhtml for JSF's servlet.